# Bug in Unanswered Tag Search

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, tag-search

> Similar bugs are posted here in previous years But this one is different

When search for `[javascript] [jquery] -[nodejs] -[reactjs]` => include JavaScript & jQuery , exclude nodejs and reactjs, it show the result as expected but when **Choose the Unanswered Tab, it shows Completely Irrelevant results**

Check the image
[image: BUG]

Check the **URL, Search Box and Tags that are listed in Right Top** and compare it with the result.